# How would I display a notification on mouseMoved?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I'd like to display a notification anytime the mouse has moved for 15 seconds.

So far I seem to understand I need to add

```
window.acceptsMouseMovedEvents = true
```

and I need to override MouseMoved

```
override func mouseMoved(with event: NSEvent) {
        //print ("MOVED!")
        timer.invalidate()
        displayNotification()
    }
```

```
    func displayNotification(){
        var timeLeft = 15

        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { timer in
            let notification = NSUserNotification()
            notification.title = "Title of notification"
            notification.subtitle = "Subtitle of notification"
            notification.soundName = NSUserNotificationDefaultSoundName
            NSUserNotificationCenter.default.deliver(notification)

            timeLeft -= 1

            if(timeLeft==0){
                timer.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }
```

I can't quite seem to get the mouseMoved part working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This took me quite a while but I finally managed to figured it out, I was missing this piece:

```
NSEvent.addGlobalMonitorForEvents(matching: [.mouseMoved]) { _ in
            self.displayNotification()
        }
```

my only issue is: the timer doesn't properly invalidate any time I move the mouse.